# CSS not applying on icons

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm watching Traversy Media's SASS Course, and I've got this problem with my icon colour not applying. Here's my HTML:

Does anyone know why the #fff colour isn't applying to my icons?

```css
.icons a {
  color: pink;
  margin: 0 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="icons my-1">
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.icons a i{color#fff}` try

Comment: It is working. At least it's working in the demo above. You must have other CSS overriding.

Comment: I see what may be a Bootstrap class. Are you using a style library?

Comment: Nico, If the icons ain't colored right, what do your dev-tools say about what style they're getting their color from. *dev-tools -> elements -> computed -> click on color*

Comment: if you apply #fff then icons won't be visible right?

Comment: I'm not using a style library but i've been creating my little framework within sass. I'll try the dev tools

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the color to the surround `<a>` tag, to apply the effect to the inner `<i>` field you need the following CSS selector:

```
.icons a i {
   color: #fff
}
```

Otherwise the selector is trying to change the color of the anchor itself, which has no color.

Comment: This usually isn't necessary. The i element inherits from the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the color to the  element

```
.icons a i {
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This usually isn't necessary. It isn't in the case of the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but nothing was working out, anyways thanks for your help, I just copy pasted the source code from Traversy Media's YouTube Video which is extremely frustrating but can't be helped! Thanks!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).